# ¿Cómo graficar seno(25x)?

Tags: latex

He intentado graficar algunas funciones trigonométricas en LaTex y lo logré pero no pude con esta sen(8πx) que se podría aproximar como sen(25x) pero parece que entre más grande sea el número que multiplica a x, LaTex empieza a mostrar la gráfica cada vez más deforme hasta que ya no la muestra. Hay alguna forma de graficar esa función?

Este es mi codigo:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw (3.14,0) node[below] {$\pi$};
\draw (-3.14,0) node[below] {$-\pi$};
\draw [color=olive, thick,domain=-3.14:3.14] plot (\x,{sin(25*\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

En la imagen 1 se ve sen(20x).
En la imagen 2 así me muestra sen(25x)

[image: Así se ve sen(20x)]

[image: Y por alguna razón así me muestra sen(25x)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos cambios, por empezar usá `smooth` para suavizar las conexiones de los puntos y por último, jugar con el parámetro `samples` para generar más puntos. Algo como esto:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw (3.14,0) node[below] {$\pi$};
\draw (-3.14,0) node[below] {$-\pi$};
\draw [color=olive, smooth, thick, domain=-3.14:3.14, samples=29] plot (\x,{sin(25*\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

'

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]